# calabash android asking permission?

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, calabash, aws-device-farm

Hi  I run a hybrid app in real device & emulator it doesn't ask runtime permissions in android. But in AWS Device Farm it asks permission. I cant find elements for Permission dialog. Can anyone help for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your tests on a device that already had the app installed and already accept the permissions they will not get re-prompted, on AWS Device Farm it is a clean install and therefor will not have any permissions pre-accepted. The tests will have to be written in a way to expect the popups and accept them.

PS.
This behavior only occurs on android 6.0 and above, 5.1 and bellow will accept permissions on install.
[See](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on that now in appium.  I found the Id to be

com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button

Using the appium inspector.  Here is the rest of the code.

https://github.com/jamesknowsbest/sample-appium-test-to-dismiss-popups/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jamesknowsbest/www/SampleTest.java